# Update Builder gives late response when multiple versions are there in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Project : Spring Boot

I'm updating my elasticsearch document using following way,

```
@Override
public Document update(DocumentDTO document) {
    try {
        Document doc = documentMapper.documentDTOToDocument(document);
        Optional<Document> fetchDocument = documentRepository.findById(document.getId());
        if (fetchDocument.isPresent()) {
            fetchDocument.get().setTag(doc.getTag());
            Document result = documentRepository.save(fetchDocument.get());
            final UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(Constants.INDEX_NAME, Constants.INDEX_TYPE, document.getId().toString());
            updateRequest.setRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.WAIT_UNTIL);
            updateRequest.doc(jsonBuilder().startObject().field("tag", doc.getTag()).endObject());
            UpdateResponse updateResponse = client.update(updateRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
            log.info("ES result : "+ updateResponse.status());
            return result;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.info(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Using this my document updated successfully and version incremented but when version goes 20+.

It takes lot many time to retrieve data(around 14sec).

I'm still confused regarding process of versioning. How it works in update and delete scenario? At time of search it process all the data version and send latest one? Is it so?

Comment: So you udpating same document and after 20+ update on the same document, it takes a lot of time? this is your query?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch internally uses Lucene which uses immutable segments to store the data. as these segments are immutable, every update on elasticsearch internally marks the old document delete(soft delete) and inserts a new document(with a new version).

The old document is later on cleanup during a [background segment merging process](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-merge.html#index-modules-merge).

A newly updated document should be available in 1 second([default refresh interval](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-modules.html#index-refresh-interval-setting)) but it can be disabled or change, so please check this setting in your index. **I can see you are using `wait_for` param in your code, please remove this and you should be able to see the updated document fast if you have not changed the default refresh_interval.**

Note:- Here both update and delete operation works similarly, the only difference is that in delete operation new document is not created, and the old document is marked soft delete and later on during segment merge deleted permanently.

Comment: Initially i tried without wait_for and i face same issue.

Comment: Can you provide the value of refresh interval in your index and how many shards and replicas you have??

Comment: @DhwanilPatel any luck?